# Animate Element to right edge of the window using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a div to the right of the window using Jquery. I am also using Jquery UI to change the color of the div. I am animating the div all over the window as well. I am just experimenting with jquery animations though, nothing critical. Any ways this is the code I have so far:

### HTML:

```
   <div id="box1"></div>

    <button type="button" id="btn"> Click Me! </button>
```

### CSS:

```
        #box1{

            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            border: 0px solid black;
            border-radius: 0px;
            position: relative;

        }

        #btn{
            position: fixed;
            top: 600px;
            display: table-cell;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
```

### JQuery:

```
var allow = true;

var animating = false;

$("#btn").click(function(){



    if(allow == true){


        if(!animating){

          animating = true;

          $("#btn").hide();



          $("#box1").animate({backgroundColor: "yellow", borderWidth: "5px"}, 1000, "linear").animate({left: "500px"}, 1000).animate({top: "500px"}, 1000);
          $("#box1").animate({left: "1000px", top: "0px"}, 1000).animate({left: "500px"}, 1000).animate({top: "500px"}, 1000, function(){
            allow =  false;
            animating = false;
            $("#btn").show().text("Click Me Aagain!");

        });

      }

  } else {

   if(!animating){
      $("#btn").hide();
      animating = true;
      $("#box1").animate({top: 0}, 1000).animate({left: 0}, 1500).animate({backgroundColor: "red", borderRadius: 0, borderWidth: 0, width: "100px", height: "100px"}, 1000, function(){

         $("#btn").show().text("Start Over!");

     });


      animating = false;
      allow = true;

  }
}



});
```

The first variable at the top is to toggle between two different animation sequences. The next is to ensure that the animations are not triggered twice by mistake. The element I am trying to move all the way to the right is #box1 and I want it to do so at the end of the first sequence!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options you can do to get the box to animate to the right edge of the area.

1) You could set the css "left: auto", and animate the css "right:0". To do this you would need to take some extra steps. You would need to set css "position: absolute" to the box and would need to wrap the box in a div that has the css "position: relative" with a width of 100%. That way, the box knows where the right edge because its most immediate parent that has css "position:relative" is setting the boundary. Doing this option would require a little fine tuning because switching between animating the left position and the right position will cause some jumping.

2) This option you could continue animating the left position, but to get it to animate to the right, you would need jquery to calculate how wide the page is, and subtract the with width of the box. It would look like this:

left: ($(document).outerWidth() - $('#box1').outerWidth())